# How to split an array element in java

Tags: java, arrays, json, file-io

I am reading some data from the internet into my array like this:

```
final String[] relations = entity.getAsJsonPrimitive("rel").getAsString().substring(1).split("\\/");
final String relation = entity.getAsJsonPrimitive("rel").getAsString();
System.out.println(relations[1]);
       break;
```

Anyway, the output is really weird (without the break statement the output is hundred of lines) since after I added the break statement I am getting two lines of output like this:

```
proerty
is_a
```

How can I split this output to print only the first or the second line?
I checked how the function spilt works but it did not work for me it says "ArrayIndexOutOfBound" 
Also, would any one tell me why the first index contains hundred of lines but the second index throws an error when I print it and says out of bound.

This is the input, which is only one element. The real input has hundreds elements like this one:
Note: I want to print the relation part only.

```
{
      "context": "/ctx/all",
      "dataset": "/d/verbosity",
      "end": "/c/en/sleep",
      "features": [
        "/c/en/bed /r/RelatedTo -",
        "/c/en/bed - /c/en/sleep",
        "- /r/RelatedTo /c/en/sleep"
      ],
      "id": "/e/bffe7778135422c9fc697e5c3ada0be01ef026f0",
      "license": "/l/CC/By-SA",
      "rel": "/r/RelatedTo",
      "source_uri": "/s/site/verbosity",
      "sources": [
        "/s/site/verbosity"
      ],
      "start": "/c/en/bed",
      "surfaceText": "[[bed]] is related to [[sleep]]",
      "uri": "/a/[/r/RelatedTo/,/c/en/bed/,/c/en/sleep/]",
      "weight": 6.954197039975413
    },
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the input which generated that output?  This is not clear to me.

Comment: Please provide the value of the relation variable.

Comment: Use a JSON parser to handle your JSON content.